# Java add PostgreSQL Driver to Class Path

Tags: java, postgresql, classpath

I have a script that I would like to use to interface with a PostgreSQL database but I'm struggling a bit to include the driver when executing.

The Java code is very basic at the moment

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class l_connect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch(Exception log) {
            System.out.println(log);
        }

    }

}
```

If I execute this

```
# java l_connect
```

it does what I expect it to; outputs the exception log that it can't find the driver

I downloaded the postgresql driver and placed it in a directory in my project and then tried to execute it

```
# java -cp ".;../assets/postgresql-9.4-1202.jdbc4.jar" l_connect
```

and I get the error

```
# Error: Could not find or load main class l_connect
```

Why would this be happening? Is my usage of java -cp not correct?

*UPDATE*

I forgot to mention that my system is Fedora 22 Linux and I am not using an IDE I am using the terminal

Comment: Try the classpath without quotes `java -cp .;../assets/postgresql-9.4-1202.jdbc4.jar l_connect`. Also the error message indicates _your_ class was not found, not the driver. Did you **compile** your Java class before trying to run it? ( `javac l_connect.java`?)

Comment: In Linux the path separator is `:` not `;` so you should use `java -cp .:../assets/postgresql-9.4-1202.jdbc4.jar`

Comment: Oh I didn't realise I was using ';', Thanks so much, I was looking everywhere except there -_-

Comment: And please, don't ever put your classes in the default package, and respect the Java naming conventions. Classes are CamelCased.

Comment: @JB Nizet, I don't understand what you mean about classes being in the default package, Java isn't my primary programming language so classes are very new to me

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/

Answer (score 0):

May be this would help some one.
export CLASSPATH=/myapp1.jar:/myapp2.jar